# What's the difference between $1 and ? in db.query

Tags: postgresql, go

Can someone please explain me what is the difference between using

> $1

```
query, err := b.Db.Prepare("SELECT id, name, owner, coordinates, reason_froggy FROM Business WHERE name ilike $1")
    if err != nil {
        return business_list, err
    }
    rows, err := query.Query("%" + business + "%")
    if err != nil {
        return business_list, err
    }
```

and

> ?

```
query, err := b.Db.Prepare("SELECT id, name, owner, coordinates, reason_froggy FROM Business WHERE name ilike ?")
    if err != nil {
        return business_list, err
    }
    rows, err := query.Query("%" + business + "%")
    if err != nil {
        return business_list, err
    }
```

are they're supposed to work the same way as an anon param, or they're different?

Also the other thing is that with the **$1** param the query runs perfect, but with the **?** param the query returns a pg error in syntax.

Comment: `$1` style notation is useful if you want to send a parameter value once, but use it say in multiple places in a single query.

Comment: Executive summary: PostgreSQL uses numbered placeholders (`$1`, `$2`, ...) natively and the low level Go interfaces use the database's native placeholders.